# SQL Filter Null Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like

```
select *
from tableName
where x='3'
```

This gives me back some number of results, but I don't want to see any columns where every row is Null. Is there an easy way to filter those out?

Comment: Do you mean where certain *columns* are NULL? Which ones? This won't return rows where `x` is NULL, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there isn't.

What you are after is some syntax like

```
select <column list::filter(where all rows are NULL)>
```

However, it just doesn't make sense. Not in a general sense. It might look cool when used in SSMS or a one-off query tool, but for day-to-day usage by Joe Public in programs like ASP.Net, who'd want an unpredictable number of columns?

Now if you really wanted to do it, this can be achieved with dynamic SQL, but it would have to be coded ONCE-PER-TABLE that you want to query this way.

Comment: Gotcha, I am doing one-off thing, and I can see why it wouldn't make sense in the general case. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try some crazy stuff with dynamics SQL but I really wouldn’t recommend this.

This query checks if first two columns have all null values and then adds them to select statement. If you really want to go this way you can to the same for  all columns in your table.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(1000)
DECLARE @columnList nvarchar(1000)
SET @columnList = ''

DECLARE @tableRowCount int
DECLARE @columnRowCount int

SET @tableRowCount = (select COUNT(*) from tableName)

SET @columnRowCount = (select COUNT(*) from tableName where column1 is null)
IF @tableRowCount <> @columnRowCount 
    SET @columnList = @columnList + 'column1, '

SET @columnRowCount = (select COUNT(*) from tableName where column2 is null)
IF @tableRowCount <> @columnRowCount 
    SET @columnList = @columnList + 'column2, '


IF LEN(@columnList) > 0
    SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@columnList,1, LEN(@columnList) - 1) + ' FROM tableName'
ELSE
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM tableName'

EXEC(@sql)
```